# How to avoid sending multiple copy of mail

Tags: smtp, imap

I am writing one mail sending program. Which reads mail from queue and after sending delete from queue.

So process look likes:

1. Read one mail from queue
2. Send mail
3. Delete mail from queue

If application crash after step 2. Due to some programming bug or due to network error I am not able to delete mail from queue. I end up in sending multiple copies of the mail.

Is there a way, to avoid sending duplication copy of mails?  something generating unique hash and adding a custom header. And check if any mail is having same header value.

Comment: Could you name your OS? Which MTA/mail server do you use?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip 
Mail server is user choice. He can select any smtp server for sending mails. (Like gmail).

Comment: **SOME** possible solutions are "first MTA" dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no such thing as querying the mail system to find how whether a particular mail (say, with a particular header or hash value) has been sent already, there isn't really any way to do this.

Mail delivery software should take the point of view that it's better to send a duplicate mail than to not sent a queued mail at all.

You can of course take as many steps as you feel necessary to help make your application robust against errors and crashes, including making sure you catch all exceptions, `fork()`ing the application and have the child to the work while the parent monitors it, etc... Basically make every reasonable effort to dequeue the email (which is hopefully a simple operation that can't easily fail, such as for example a simple `unlink()`) as soon as possible after it has been confirmed sent.

Even then and even if your program has no bugs whatever, the network can still bite you. If you send a mail but you never get a response from the SMTP `DATA` command (say because the network connection was broken just at that point), has the email been sent or no? It's impossible to know. Should you dequeue it? No.